# jinterop Win32_Process Create

Tags: java, wmi, win32-process, j-interop

I am trying to achieve the following wmic command using j-interop.

```
wmic /NODE:192.168.0.195 /USER:Test /PASSWORD:password123 process call create "calc.exe"
```

I have my code written like this in my method.  I have two other methods that create a session and connect to the WMI service so that part is taken care of.

```
public void wmiExecute() throws JIException {

    // Obtain Win32_Process and narrow it as IJIDispatch
    Object[] params = new Object[] {
        new JIString("Win32_Process"),
        new Integer(0),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()
    };
    JIVariant[] servicesSet = this._wbemServices.callMethodA("InstancesOf", params);
    IJIDispatch wbemObjectSet = (IJIDispatch) JIObjectFactory.narrowObject(servicesSet[0].getObjectAsComObject());

    params = new Object[] {
            "calc.exe",
             JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
             JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
             new Integer(0),
    };
    wbemObjectSet.callMethodA("Create", params);
}
```

I kept getting an Exception of

```
Caught Throwable: org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Unknown name. [0x80020006]
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Unknown name. [0x80020006]
```

Any idea what could be wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution...

You shouldn't use InstanceOf to obtain Win32_Process because you will be just getting a list of currently running processes.  Instead you should use "Get" to obtain the default Win32_Process.

```
public void wmiExecute() throws JIException {

    // Obtain Win32_Process and narrow it as IJIDispatch
    Object[] params = new Object[] {
        new JIString("Win32_Process"),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
        JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()
    };

    // Obtain the default Win32_Process
    JIVariant[] service = this._wbemServices.callMethodA("Get", params);

    // Convert it to a IJIDispatch object
    IJIDispatch wbemObject = (IJIDispatch) JIObjectFactory.narrowObject(service[0].getObjectAsComObject());

    // Create input params
    Object[] paramsCalc = new Object[] {
             new JIString("calc.exe"),
             JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
             JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()
    };

    // Create the calculator process
    JIVariant[] results = wbemObject.callMethodA("Create", paramsCalc);
}
```